# How to get the rainbow effect from top left to bottom right

Tags: css

im trying to make the rainbow effect from top left to bottom right but i cant get it to keep moving

i tried alot by changing the gradient or the keyframes but it gave me a good gradient but a line that went from top to bottom

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 440px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}

.image {
    background: url(https://psxgems.com/system/cron/apisaves/Images/14968251919.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.gradient {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(255,0,0,0.6) 20%, rgba(255,127,0,0.6) 40%, rgba(255,255,0,0.6) 60%, rgba(0,255,0,0.6) 80%, rgba(0,0,255,0.06) 100%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    mask-image: url(https://psxgems.com/system/cron/apisaves/Images/14968251919.jpg);
    mask-size: cover;
    mask-position: center;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    animation: colorscroll 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes colorscroll {
    from { background-position: 0 -440px; }
    to { background-position: 0 440px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="gradient"></div>
</div>
```

Doing this

```
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(255,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(255,0,0,0.6) 20%, rgba(255,127,0,0.6) 40%, rgba(255,255,0,0.6) 60%, rgba(0,255,0,0.6) 80%, rgba(0,0,255,0.06) 100%);
```

makes it weird (it gives me the correct animation but also an line that is going from top to bottom

Comment: First of, don't forget to puyt the style in a `<head>` tag, these kinds of things could make strange things happens regardless as the browser is trying to interpret non-standard nesting and tags. Secondly, _what do you mean with "makes it weird"_? Keep in kind that _we do not know what you want to achieve_. Sometimes "weird" is the goal, and "weird" is different from person to person.

Comment: @somethinghere i try to make the gradient effect that present already go from top left to bottom right. Now its going from top to bottom.

Comment: Instead of "to bottom right" you need to use something like "135deg", which will take care of the gradient angle. But the animation still won't work as you probably expect – you'd need a background that is "mirrored" to all sides so that there are no borders when it repeats.